# Why is sizeForItemAtIndexPath never called?

Tags: swift2, uicollectionviewlayout

In my custom view controller defined as follows:

```
class Wall : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, WallLayoutDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout = WallLayout()
        layout.delegate = self


        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.registerClass(WallCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Wall.reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)

        self.collectionView = collectionView
   }
   // CODE

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
      return CGSizeMake(50, 100)
   }

}
```

The function sizeForItemAtIndexPath is never called. How it comes?

Comment: Is it calling numberOfSectionsInCollectionView and numberOfItemsInSection?

Comment: Cuz if any of these two returns 0, then sizeForItemAtIndexPath wont get called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that it is because the layout is up to me when I use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and cannot be deduced by the collection view.